# Describe the combination of eye shadow and tear

Tags: poetry

In this picture, the woman's tear has turned black because it was mixed with her eye shadow. How would you describe it in a dramatic way?

[image]

Comment: Hey there. This is the second question you've posted asking to describe a picture. Sorry to say, but that's really not something we do here.

Answer (score 1):

The bluish black streak trickled down her face, her eyes wet and overflowing with moisture. The tears, mingling with the bruised coloured make up she wore appeared as though she was crying dark, misted, and gloomy teardrops, each falling from her eyes and leaving behind them a thick, black trail staining her flushed, pink, and slightly damp cheeks.

Comment: I can't do better than that. Upvote. That's pretty long but it's good

Comment: Thanks Tasch, appreciate that. I know its pretty long winded! :)

Comment: Please try to avoid answering off-topic questions.